# D3 bar chart yaxis scaling issue, I don't want decimal/duplicate values

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js, angularjs-nvd3-directives

I have implemented D3 chart using NVD3 library below is the link for the reference.
Is there a way that I can stop this automatic scaling or get rid of this decimal values.
http://nvd3.org/livecode/index.html#codemirrorNav

[image]

[image]

Comment: this a plunker  to play around http://plnkr.co/edit/6t5bky?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got solution for this issue, problem happens when we have small set of data in which sometimes we get decimal values and when we format for integer values it duplicates the data on Y-axis.
Have a look to this plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/yFyShQ?p=preview

To make it dynamic you can pass min and max value to

```
d3.range(minValue, maxValue)
```

Like this

```
const minValue = d3.min(data, d => d.Value);
const maxValue = d3.max(data, d => d.Value);
const tickValues = d3.range(minValue > 0 ? 0 : minValue,maxValue);
return maxValue < 10 ? tickValues: null;
```